# Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a React Native application that *did* compile absolutely fine.

After installing `react-native-sentry` and automatically linking via `react-native link`, I am faced with this problem:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Users/dan/Sites/app/node_modules/react-native-intercom/iOS/../../../ios/Pods/React/node_modules/exit-hook.
```

This error occurred after I ran `pod install`

`Podfile`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'app' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for app
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.4.0'
  pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'

  platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'app-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for app-tvOS

  target 'app-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I've not modified the RNIntercom project at all, this problem **always** occurs after I try to install a new library via cocoa.

Comment: I think this link will help you https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom/issues/40

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know the outcome

Comment: @NisargThakkar it didn't work unfortunately, I am not using cocoapods for Intercom. I've embedded it as a framework. I tried the `SRCROOT` answer but that didn't work either.

Comment: The issue's not specific to the library, it flips between Intercom and AppCenterReactNative

Comment: pod install overwrites some files which might be in you gitignore, so it will not work, even if you revert every change you will face the problem. Recently i faced similar issue while implementing codepush. I had to reset everything and go back and linked codepush manually.

Comment: Yeah great insight @Abhishek - I had to delete my pod folder, then `react-native link` to throw react native link off that I "wasn't using Pods", then once installed I ran a pod install to get my original Pods directory back.

Comment: i still don't know why this happens. i guess it something to do with project setup, but my project was setup by someone else i don't have much time to dig into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and had to go in and remove a few header search paths, as described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/troubleshooting#argument-list-too-long-recursive-header-expansion-failed

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed
>
> In the
>   project's build settings, User Search Header Paths and Header Search
>   Paths are two configs that specify where Xcode should look for #import
>   header files specified in the code. For Pods, CocoaPods uses a default
>   array of specific folders to look in. Verify that this particular
>   config is not overwritten, and that none of the folders configured are
>   too large. If one of the folders is a large folder, Xcode will attempt
>   to recursively search the entire directory and throw above error at
>   some point.
>
> To revert the User Search Header Paths and Header Search Paths build
>   settings to their defaults set by CocoaPods - select the entry in the
>   Build Settings panel, and hit delete. It will remove the custom
>   override and return to the CocoaPod defaults.

[image: error]