# Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at react-native-google-cast

Tags: xcode, react-native, google-cast

I have a problem with building a app in Xcode. When i try to build the app it gives the following error.

```
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Users/******/Documents/******/******/app/native-app/node_modules/react-native-google-cast/ios/../../../ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNIap.build/Debug-iphonesimulator.
```

Checkt the repo but no solution found. Who can help me with this so i can build the app.

Info:
RN version: 0.52.0
react-native-google-cast: 2.10.4.1
Xcode: 9.4.1

Thanks,
Yarno

Comment: Check out this GitHub issue https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1407

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Keep you posted!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and had to go in and remove a few header search paths, as described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/troubleshooting#argument-list-too-long-recursive-header-expansion-failed

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed
>
> In the
>   project's build settings, User Search Header Paths and Header Search
>   Paths are two configs that specify where Xcode should look for #import
>   header files specified in the code. For Pods, CocoaPods uses a default
>   array of specific folders to look in. Verify that this particular
>   config is not overwritten, and that none of the folders configured are
>   too large. If one of the folders is a large folder, Xcode will attempt
>   to recursively search the entire directory and throw above error at
>   some point.
>
> To revert the User Search Header Paths and Header Search Paths build
>   settings to their defaults set by CocoaPods - select the entry in the
>   Build Settings panel, and hit delete. It will remove the custom
>   override and return to the CocoaPod defaults.

(Also cross-posted on this similar issue: [Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318129/argument-list-too-long-recursive-header-expansion-failed/58357205#58357205))

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue in Xcode 10.1, just move your code folder location from desktop, document etc to home folder.